# FREEDOM K64F Low Power Timer LPTIMER usage and configuration

Tags: microcontroller

i'm trying to manage some pulse width measurements with my FRDM K64F board, but everithing seems very difficult. Firstly i'm working on IAR embedded workbench and a RTOS micrium uC/OS, secondly i have some constraints like the usage of the LPTIMER and interrupts. My background is based on PIC 8bit microcontrollers.

How do i have to start working? 
On the datasheet there is no reference on any pinout or other helpful information, do you have some tutorial or guidelines?
thanks really so much.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. I don't understand whether you have a software or hardware problem (this site is only for programming questions!), anyway your question is quite broad and you are even asking for some tutorials, which is against the guidelines of this site (from the rules: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.") So please ask a more specific question. Thank you!

Comment: ok,i'm sorry for my errors, i repeat clearly my question. How do i have to proceed in order to CONTROL and CONFIGURE the LPTIMER of my freedom board? The datasheet is very difficult and i can not figure out how to do this. Your help will be very appreciated.